# Why variable is not available in controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileLeftMenu">
<li ng-class="{'active':selectedTab == 'personal'}" ng-click="selectedTab = 'personal'" class=""><a href="1">Personal</a>
</li>
</div>
```

And controller:

```
 $scope.selectedTab = 'first';
 if ($routeParams.page) {
   ajax.get(page, function (CbData) {
       $scope.selectedTab = page;
   });
 }
```

So, if do:

```
{{selectedTab}}
```

in template HTML  get always: `first`

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(CbData)` from within your ajax callback? Is your ajax request working? And why are you using `ajax` anyway when Angular has it's own `$http` service? Could you create a demo on plunker?

Comment: Ajax working, it loads data in this HTML. If do `console.log($scope.selectedTab);` inside callback I see value from `$routeParams.page`. It works

Comment: May be controller is loaded early then works AJAX callback?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to debug the problem if you either posted your code in a more complete form or, much better, reproduced the problem on http://plnkr.co/

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ChMaiougIW4KiNNkUTlO?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `$scope` variable with the new `$routeParams` just after the change in route. For that you can listen for the`$routeChangeSuccess` event. Try this:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6fksCooe5GFkbe9MeWAn?p=preview)

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
      .when('/test/:page', {

        templateUrl: function(params) {
          return 'pidat.html';
        },

        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      });

  }

]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

  // when controller is loaded params are empty
  console.log('on controller load $routeParams', $routeParams);

  $scope.name = 'World';

  // only after you have transitioned to the new 
  // route will your $routeParams change so we
  // need to listen for $routeChangeSuccess
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){

      console.log('on $routeChangeSuccess load $routeParams', $routeParams);

    if ($routeParams.page) {
       $scope.name = $routeParams.page;
    }
  });

}]);
```

So for your original example you would probably have to do something like this:

```
$scope.selectedTab = 'first';

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){

   if ($routeParams.page) {
       ajax.get(page, function (CbData) {
           $scope.selectedTab = page;
       });
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the angular $http service (`$http.get()`), not `ajax.get()`. Otherwise, Angular isn't aware of the change you make to the scope once the HTTP response comes and the callback is executed, unless you call `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: `ajax`is name of service. `$scope.$apply()` does not help - I get error: ` [$rootScope:inprog]`

Comment: ajax is the name of what service? If ajax is the name you gave to the $http service, then 1. don't do that, 2. the syntax is `$http.get(url).then(function(response) {...})`, or `$http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {...})`

Comment: Problem is not in AJAX

Comment: If you know what the problem is, why are you asking? Why don't you answer the questions you're being asked, and provide a plunkr?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ChMaiougIW4KiNNkUTlO?p=preview  But how to send params for URL?