# Why is not changed variable from routing Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/ChMaiougIW4KiNNkUTlO

When I click to link I get loaded HTML from file. Also in variable:

```
$scope.name = $routeParams.page;
```

I get value from URL  `$routeParams.page`.

But why `$scope.name` is not changes on template?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625577/why-variable-is-not-available-in-controller/31664227#31664227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to listen for the `$routeChangeSuccess` event

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){

   //.. check $routeParams here for change
   $scope.name = $routeParams.page;
});
```

Wait didn't you ask this earlier...?